# On meaning and syntactic structure of "usque eo quoad his sex annis"

Tags: grammar-identification, conjunction, time, clauses, english--latin-translation

I am reading the Latin version of *the Little Prince*, namely *Regulus*, translated by Auguste Haury. In the beginning of Chap. 2, I saw this sentence a little hard for me:

> Sic aetatem solus egi nec quisquam praesto fuit quocum vere colloquerer **usque eo quoad his sex annis** in Garamentum solitudine destitutus jacui.

There is already a main verb **egi** in front, so **jacui** requires a conjunction, here I think **quoad**. In Ketherline Woods' English version, the same sentence is translated as

> until I had an accident with my plane in the Desert of Sahara, six years ago.

But I don't know how **usque eo quoad his sex annis** can be understood like this: I don't get the meaning of **eo** and **quoad** here.

How to parse the syntactic structure of this sentence?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Quoad** here is a correlative of *usque eo*. i.e., thus/so far (*usque eo*) until/that (*quoad*).

syntactically it is like the more common *(usque) adeo/eo... ut/quo/dum/donec*. like this Seneca's example

> Haec **usque eo** animum Socratis non moverant **ut** ne vultum quidem moverint [**so far** (*usque eo*)... **to the extent that** (*ut*)...

Here another example from Cicero:

> atque hoc scitis omnes, **usque adeo** hominem in periculo fuisse **quoad** scitum est Sestium vivere (And you are all aware that he was in danger [**so long**] **until** it was ascertained that Sestius was alive; (Yonge) .

It is somewhat unusual (and probably makes it more difficult to parse) that in this passage from *Regulus* *quoad* is right next to the *eo*, whereas most of the examples do have the "antecedent" between them. In fact, there is no *(usque) eo quoad* in PHI, and [only one](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=eo%20quoad) *usque adeo quoad* (but *[usque eo ut](https://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=usque%20eo%20ut)* is more common); Thus, here, the *usque eo* relates to what comes before (*aetatem ... colloquerer*), so like the example from Cicero it should be understood: "I was without anyone to talk to **until** I was laying abandoned six years ago"

Comment: *his sex annis = abhinc sex annos* – this is well attested (e.g. Plin. Nat. hist. 14, 43: *septem his annis in Narbonensis provinciae Alba Helvia inventa est vitis uno die deflorescens*), although somewhat unclear in this context. It is at least strongly suggested by the perfect *jacui*, though. There are [two translations](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/616) of the book; the one by Franz Schlosser is allegedly better. I wonder how he rendered this.

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel, thanks. fixed that.